# MVC, C#, SQL Server : I want to create web application and perform CRUD operation on large amount of Data

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-4, orm

I want to create one web application which create reports, perform calculations, CRUD operations.

I am confused here to use ORM or not. I gone through various ORM tools like Entity Framework (which I prefer not to use), Dapper etc. but still confused which one is the best because my application will be not be effective if performance lose points.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](//meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: Any ORM will reduce performance compared to low level data access, but provide benefits of easier development and maintainability.  I'm going to vote to close as the question is both broad and primarily opinion-based.